# Add error bars to points in different layers -ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add confidence intervals to the points displayed in the attached plot using ggplot2. (2 datasets, one X axis, 2 Y axes)

The points represent the mean value (val column in the dataframe). The data frame also contains the upper and lower values (L and U columns)

```
t<-data.frame(rep(c( "AA","AG","GG"),2), c(79.29365,47.67004,22.86688,28.41990,33.29651,36.76852),
           c(71.18651,45.97425,22.04625,27.23392,32.97892,36.57194),
           c(87.40079,49.36582,23.68751,29.60588,33.61411,36.96510),
           c(rep("a",3),c(rep("b",3))))
colnames(t)<-c("x","val","L","U","panel")

d1<-t[1:3,]
d2<-t[4:6,]

p <- ggplot(data = t, mapping = aes(x =t$x, y = t$val))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel ~ ., scale = "free")
p <- p + layer(data = d1, mapping=aes(x = d1$x, y = d1$val), geom = c( "point"), stat = "identity",size=3) 
p <- p + layer(data = d2, mapping =aes(x = d2$x, y = d2$val),geom = "point", stat = "identity",size=3)
p<-p+theme_bw()
p<-p+xlab("Genotypes")+ylab("Quantitative trait")+ggtitle("RS")
p<-p+scale_color_hue()
p
```

[image]

I have managed to plot the error bars in a simple ggplot graph for one dataset, however I am failing to correctly add them to both plots as I have tried to do above.

```
ggplot(d1, aes(x = d1$x, y = d1$val)) +  geom_point(colour="gray", size = 4)+geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = d1$U, ymin = d1$L),width=0.05) +theme_bw()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following command to the existing plot and everything will work fine:

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = U, ymin = L), width = 0.05)
```

Note. I refer to `U` and `L` instead of `d1$U` and `d1$L`. The errorbar limits of both layers are already present in `t`.

[image]